# Uniform convergence of sequence of almost everywhere zero functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $B([a , b])$ be the space of bounded and measurable functions from a closed bounded interval $[a , b]$ into $\mathbb R$ endowed with the sup norm. I know that this is a Banach space.

Now consider the following vector subspace of  $B([a , b])$:

$$L_{0} = \{ f : [a , b] → R │ f  =  0 \text{ almost everywhere} \}$$

How to show that $L_{0}$ is a closed subspace of $B([a , b])$.

My attempt is as follows:

Let  $f  \in B([a , b])$ be a limit point of  $L_{0}$ . Then there is a sequence $( f_{n} )$ in $L_{0}$ such that
$f_{n} → f$  uniformly and hence $f_{n} (x) = f (x)$ for all $x \in [a , b]$. Now since $f_{n} = 0$ a.e for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and  since countable intersection of  full measure subsets is a full measure subset therefore  $f  = 0$ a.e.
Any correction if am wrong is greatly appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f_n)\in L_0^{\mathbb N}$ a sequence of $L_0$ that converges to a function $f$. In particular, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e. and thus $f=0$ a.e. Therefore, $L_0$ is sequentially closed and thus closed.